# mount: special device sda/sda1 does not exist

Tags: linux, mount, docker

I'm working on a IoT Edge device based on Linux Yocto (arm_v7) and I need to mount an USB Drive.

Linux version:

```
root@7426a4ffc838:/# uname -a
Linux 7426a4ffc838 4.9.80-rt62 #1 SMP PREEMPT RT Thu May 14 17:11:08 UTC 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Since this device has no shell (only webpage), I use an docker container to try to mount the USB drive.

My container runs in privileged mode in order to access to hardware.

If I run the command "lsblk" I get this output:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0 363.6M  1 loop 
sda           8:0    1  14.8G  0 disk 
`-sda1        8:1    1  14.8G  0 part 
mmcblk0     179:0    0   7.4G  0 disk 
|-mmcblk0p1 179:1       61.1M  0 part 
|-mmcblk0p2 179:2    0  61.1M  0 part 
`-mmcblk0p3 179:3    0   7.3G  0 part
```

My USB drive is named "sda".

So if I try to mount the USB Drive with the command `mount /sda/sda1 /mnt/usb/`, I get this error:

```
mount: special device /sda/sda1 does not exist
```

Is there a way to mount this drive?

Thanks in advance for the help.

BR,
Federico

Answer (score 4):

Even if `lsblk` might discover the device (through `/sys/`), `mount` still requires a valid block device to mount from. If it wasn't created, either because the embedded device doesn't run a tool like `udev` or because the container's environment doesn't provide an adequately populated `/dev/` directory like would be the host, one can still create it manually.

One should verify the block major/minor with the output of `lsblk -o NAME,MAJ:MIN`, let's suppose the relevant part displays:

```
# lsblk -o NAME,MAJ:MIN
NAME                MAJ:MIN
[...]
sda                   8:0  
`-sda1                8:1  
[...]
```

then the needed block device can be created with the previous information:

```
mknod /dev/sda1 b 8 1
```

which should now be able to be mounted with:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

As it's embedded, there might be further issues if the driver for the filesystem on this partition isn't built in kernel and for some reason it's not auto-loaded. So if that doesn't work on the first try, be sure to have the module explicitly loaded (eg: `modprobe vfat`) or builtin (recompile kernel...). Some filesystems wouldn't be so easy to use (eg: `exfat` didn't have direct kernel support in Linux 4.9 and would require FUSE).

Answer (score 3):

There is no such directory as `/sda`.

What you actually want to do is mount `/dev/sda1`:

`mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/usb/`

Comment: I also tried you suggestion, but I gate the same error: mount: "special device /dev/sda1 does not exist"